# Jekyll template, Feeling-Responsive importing image

Tags: jekyll, html, github-pages

I am using the Jekyll "Feeling-Responsive" theme (https://github.com/Phlow/feeling-responsive) for my github page.  I want to include my own .jpg image to display with a widget on the front page, so I edited the corresponding "image" field in index.md with the name of my image, but no image shows for that widget, while the other widgets still display their stock images.  Not sure how to proceed, any help would be appreciated.

Here is my index.md file,  I've altered the image field for widget1.

---

```
layout: frontpage
header:
  image_fullwidth: header_unsplash_12.jpg

widget1:
  title: "Portfolio"
  url: 'http://phlow.github.io/feeling-responsive/blog/'
  text: 'Some of my past and current work (under construction)'
  image: figure__atom.jpg 
  <!-- image: widget-1-302x182.jpg -->

widget2:
  title: "Why use this theme?"
  url: 'http://phlow.github.io/feeling-responsive/info/'
  text: '<em>Feeling Responsive</em> is heavily customizable.<br/>1. Language-Support :)<br/>2. Optimized for speed and it&#39;s responsive.<br/>3. Built on <a href="http://foundation.zurb.com/">Foundation Framework</a>.<br/>4. Seven different Headers.<br/>5. Customizable navigation, footer,...'
  video: '<a href="#" data-reveal-id="videoModal"><img src="http://phlow.github.io/feeling-responsive/images/start-video-feeling-responsive-302x182.jpg" width="302" height="182" alt=""/></a>'

widget3:
  title: "Download Theme"
  url: 'https://github.com/Phlow/feeling-responsive'
  image: widget-github-303x182.jpg
  text: '<em>Feeling Responsive</em> is free and licensed under a MIT License. Make it your own and start building. Grab the <a href="https://github.com/Phlow/feeling-responsive/tree/bare-bones-version">Bare-Bones-Version</a> for a fresh start or learn how to use it with the <a href="https://github.com/Phlow/feeling-responsive/tree/gh-pages">education-version</a> with sample posts and images. Then tell me via Twitter <a href="http://twitter.com/phlow">@phlow</a>.'
#
# Use the call for action to show a button on the frontpage
#
# To make internal links, just use a permalink like this
# url: /getting-started/
#
# To style the button in different colors, use no value
# to use the main color or success, alert or secondary.
# To change colors see sass/_01_settings_colors.scss
#
callforaction:
  url: https://tinyletter.com/feeling-responsive
  text: Inform me about new updates and features ›
  style: alert
permalink: /index.html
#
# This is a nasty hack to make the navigation highlight
# this page as active in the topbar navigation
#
homepage: true
---

<div id="videoModal" class="reveal-modal large" data-reveal="">
  <div class="flex-video widescreen vimeo" style="display: block;">
    <iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3b5zCFSmVvU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! please provide the code so we can help you effectively!

Comment: Yes. Dray is right. Several issues could cause this. Ensure your path is used, not the phlow's url. If that doesn't work, please provide a link to your github repo so we help.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit _config.yml file with your images directory for parameter "urlimg:"